# What would be a proper way to handle tokens in monolith application?

Tags: php, laravel, rest

I have a monolith web application powered by Laravel. Users access different forms and some of them have button on them that executes Ajax call to the back-end (example relative endpoint: `api/external/get-current-temperature`). A back-end function that handles the request than connects to an external service via API and obtain data, writes some log in database and pass data back to requestor (front-end user). But in order to execute any API call it has to authenticate and obtain a Token.

**Question:**
I have multiple users that can potentially request `api/external/get-current-temperature` at the same time. How should I handle authorization/token? Should I store it in database and check its expiration time before requesting a new one or what? How would I refresh it? - The external provide has no specific function that could be utilized to verify token. But I know for sure the token is valid 60 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The users of your application never have to be mixed up / mistaken with your foreign API. You can and should provide you own mechanism (i.e. tokens) to authenticate any users. If users are authenticated the external API is used, else an error-message could be provided by your application.

As users also fill several different form it's quite possible that you save some user-data. If every user has own authentication credentials it's easy and much more secure to provide only the user's own data. If you use for every user the same authentication token in your own application you might get the situation that one user can see data from another user.

So see it like this:
You / your application is the user of the external API, therefore you need only one authenticqation token for it. Your application users use the external API as a service and as that you should provide it in your app. The data though that are provided to the service might differ from user to user.

**Example payment application:**
The API is always the same, you as developer get an API key, but the payments are for every user of your application differently. As developer you might never even able to see, store or track the user-data that are exchanged between the foreign service and the user, but your app serves as hub and provides perhaps also some products or services that are considered in any payments.

Comment: Users indeed do not need to know anything about external API and service. My back-end receives request from user, connects to external API, obtains a token and request specific set of data. When next request from whichever users comes to my back-end app in a short time the back-end does not know to obtain token once again. Should the token be stored somewhere in database and checked against its expiration details or? I am not sure about that part ...

Comment: as long as it's not security relevant to save token or even info what the user requested you could save it in a cookie on the client side (on the user's device).
Else the way to save it related to each user would likely require a database or some comparable method to save the data safely. Consider that cookies can get deleted or lost and the info has to be recovered perhaps, so it's no datastore you can rely on.

Comment: The most simple method to provide the one existing token to all users is in link-URLs. If you call a page with google map in all  map-related links is the API-key included, which is then compared with the registered Domains by Google.